# Vector operation on Pyspark dataframe: angles between two vectors

Tags: vector, pyspark

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[10, 8, 7, 6], [3, 5, 9 ,2], [1, 3, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9, 3], [2, 8, 2, 0], [8, 7, 3, 6]], list('ABCD'))
df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
| 10|  8|  7|  6|
|  3|  5|  9|  2|
|  1|  3|  4|  7|
|  1|  5|  9|  3|
|  2|  8|  2|  0|
|  8|  7|  3|  6|
+---+---+---+---+
```

transfer cols into vector by `VectorAssembler`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
Vector = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['A','B'], outputCol="Vector_AB").transform(df)
Vector = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['C','D'], outputCol="Vector_CD").transform(Vector)
Vector.show()

    +---+---+---+---+----------+---------+
    |  A|  B|  C|  D| Vector_AB|Vector_CD|
    +---+---+---+---+----------+---------+
    | 10|  8|  7|  6|[10.0,8.0]|[7.0,6.0]|
    |  3|  5|  9|  2| [3.0,5.0]|[9.0,2.0]|
    |  1|  3|  4|  7| [1.0,3.0]|[4.0,7.0]|
    |  1|  5|  9|  3| [1.0,5.0]|[9.0,3.0]|
    |  2|  8|  2|  0| [2.0,8.0]|[2.0,0.0]|
    |  8|  7|  3|  6| [8.0,7.0]|[3.0,6.0]|
    +---+---+---+---+----------+---------+
```

How to calculate angles between `Vector_AB` and `Vector_CD`?

Is there any built-in function that can do this calculate?

I try to:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
angle_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y : x.dot(y) / (Vectors.norm(x,p=2) * Vectors.norm(y,p=2)),FloatType())
Vector = Vector.withColumn("Angle", angle_udf("Vector_AB","Vector_CD")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `acos`, `dot` and `norm` functions to calculate the angle between vectors.

The formula we will use is

```
angle = f.acos(x.dot(y) / (norm(x) * norm(y))
```

PySpark Vector (for dot and norm): https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.Vectors.html

Cos inverse function:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.acos.html

Comment: I try to:
`from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors`

`angle_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y : F.acos(x.dot(y) / (Vectors.norm(x,p=2) * Vectors.norm(y,p=2))),VectorUDT())`

`Vector = Vector.withColumn("Angle",angle_udf("Vector_AB","Vector_CD"))`

Then I get the error:
` PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0.4474575643275654 of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.', from , line 2.`

Comment: Don't use udf, it wil drastically impact the performance. Use only spark APIs

Comment: How to calculate in columns? `Vector.withColumn("Angle", F.acos(Vector['Vector_AB'].dot(Vector['Vector_CD']) / (norm(Vector['Vector_AB']) * norm(Vector['Vector_CD']))))`